# How do I spend reputation points on a question?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I read at some point that I could spend my points on questions, to increase the likelihood of the question being answered and provide greater reward to the person answering the question. I recall being prompted before, but I didn't see it as an option when I went to post a question on StackOverflow just a moment ago -- so I must not be remembering correctly.

How do I spend my reputation points on a question?

Comment: Please see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a bounty to your question after it's been posted for two days. [Here's the FAQ entry.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: No, it doesn't include that, but it links to the dupe that does include that.